# Is it acceptable to decompile someone else's code for the purpose of learning what they did, and how they did it?

Tags: source-code, ethics

I am not talking about stealing code, or reusing someone's for profit. But I am assuming that if a program or plugin is distributed in a format where I can't readily view the source, that is a deliberate action on the part of the programmer.

Is it acceptable to look anyway, for the purpose of learning? And if so, are there limitations to that freedom?

Comment: I assume that you can't "readily view the source" because you've already asked and been turned down? The author might be willing to explain the general approach, would that be good enough without code? You won't know until you ask them.

Comment: No, actually, I was assuming no contact with the author, either through lack of response or availability.

Comment: And I hadn't on a practical level even considered asking. Which I should have, although I wouldn't necessarily expect someone to want to be interrupted by every try to be coder who wants to look at their code.

Comment: How will anyone tell you've done it? Will the distributor of the program or plugin have the ability to tell? No? Then do it. "Intellectual Property" is false to facts: multiple people often invent the same thing. The prohibition on reverse engineering is a consequence of the false conception of idea-as-property, and has no real moral standing.

Comment: They wouldn't be able to tell. So if it was your code you'd be ok with it?

Comment: Are you trying to learn something general, or is there some *specific* technique or concept that you are trying to learn? For instance, say you had a Photoshop plugin that converted .jpg to .ico, and you wanted to know how to write a .ico format. There might be other ways you can obtain the information, if it's something specific.

Comment: This question reminds me of DeadAIM, which for those who don't know, was an AIM addon from 10+ years ago. The guy reversed engineered the AIM client in order to figure out how to interact with the AIM client and also to find out the AIM protocol.

Comment: The case I was considering is a plug in for Outlook 2010 that writes a default reply to: email address regardless of what address the email was sent to. I've already purchased it, and am using it. I'm partly interested in seeing what was done because I want to know why it requires a plug in, and is not a default option. Partly, because I'm a curious bastard, and i like to take things apart. The data I'm after is peripheral to the plug in. I'm not looking for his code or to duplicate his project.

Comment: @zenbike, I think this is completely possible in Outlook without a plugin using a Rules and possibly a few simple Macros in combination with a Rule.  Unless I misunderstand what this plugin is actually doing, it sounds INSANELY simple to pull off and especially not warranting closed-source pay license software.

Comment: ... Further, if this is a closed source pay license software then simply by asking for the source they will probably tell you to bugger off.  Even doing this could attract unwanted attention from the company as well possibly resulting in software license audits and other things you wouldn't want to happen to your grandma on her best day.

Comment: I'm one guy, and out of their jurisdiction. But I want to do it right. That's why I asked the question. There are macros which claim to do the same thing, but they don't work on reply to. Only new mail. I'm just starting to look into it. If there's a better way, awesome.

Comment: @Bruce. +100 for "The prohibition on reverse engineering is a consequence of the false conception of idea-as-property, and has no real moral standing."  Unfortunately it does have a legal standing.  If the software gets reverse-engineered, and the vendor finds out, you could get a cease and desist letter, or worse, especially if it is explicitly mentioned in the EULA. :(

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and opinions. For those out there who I've seemed to worry with the question, I will not be doing anything without permission from the author. I really am interested in this as an example, in my opinion, of the ambiguity between legalism and actual morality. I appreciate the input.

Comment: Snerk.   Got more than 1K views, so it gets closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You indicated in one of your responses that you were more interested in knowing if the author would be upset by it... so if it were me, and you only did it for educational purposes and we met and you told me about it, then no. I would not be upset if you decompiled/reverse engineered my code. If the code in question was very kludgy/hackish and ugly, I might be a bit embarrassed, but I doubt I'd flip out (in fact, I might even be flattered that someone found my code so cool and interesting they just had to find out how it worked and went to such lengths to do so) - and hey, it might even be fun to talk about it!

Comment: What if he didn't do all these things? And what if he didn't do it for educational purposes?

Comment: VJo: Then OP would have been asking a different question, and I would have given a different answer.

Comment: I'd tell him my original code is very beautiful but his decompiler sucks, that's why it looks like crap. :)

Comment: I got a lot of great feedback from this question. I'm choosing to mark yours as accepted because it was upvoted most, and the answer most closely followed my original question.

Answer (score 4):

The legality of decompiling depends on your jurisdiction.  This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler#Legality) has some notes on US and EU law in this area.  The summary is that the legality depends on *why* you are doing it:

- If you are doing it to achieve interoperability, you *may* be allowed to do it.
- If you are doing it to "learn" or out of curiosity, you are *probably* not allowed to do it.  (I've never heard of any case law that says that educational fair use doctrine extends to decompiling software.  But ask a real lawyer.)

Whether decompiling is an "acceptable" thing to do is a value judgement, and it depends on your perspective.  Most IT professionals would probably say it is not acceptable behavior.  And certainly the copyright owner is likely to say that it is unacceptable ... and he / she / they are the ones who could decide to sue your pants off!

Comment: Ok. That last one is more what I'm trying to get a feel for. Don't you have to be doing to learn i order to achieve interoperability? Or does that mean you must be successful in order to be legal?

Comment: @zenbike:  Get a lawyer.  Seriously.

Comment: @David Thornley: A lawyer is not an ethicist.

Comment: @Frustrated No, but he might be able to keep the OP out of jail.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner:  And what are the ethics of the situation?  I can explain whether it's ethical or not according to my principles (the result:  yes, it is ethical), but not everybody will agree with my principles or reasoning.  Legality is something that more people can objectively agree on.

Comment: Guys, I'm not looking to do something illegal or immoral. I was more wondering what the viewpoint was from the guys who matter. You know, the ones who write the code. As I said, I hadn't considered just asking whatever that says about me, and I've already sent him an email.

Comment: bit inaccurate, as many legislatures allow decompilation for educational purposes.

Comment: @vartec - evidence please.

Comment: @zenbike - beware.  If a judge or jury is asked to decide if you have broken copyright law, they are not likely to be convinced by excuses involving convoluted/contorted logic.  They are more likely to say "nah ... that's bulls**t ... you are guilty".  TALK TO A LAWYER if you are intending to do something that could be illegal.

Comment: @Stephen: eg. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/73830/is-it-legal-to-disassemble-a-microsoft-dll-and-post-the-result-on-my-blog/73910#73910 - in case of that legislature is explicitly for "interoperability _or_ R&D"

Comment: @zenbike - They would be sueing for damages.  If all you did was read their code and did not copy it or try to duplicate the functionality then there are no damages.   If you disclose what you know then you start opening yourself up for them.  There is also fair use.  If you were arrested for the decompiling under criminal statutes in the US or EU you should have a fair use defense so long as you did not change, or communicate what you learned about it.

Comment: @Chad - I hope you will agree that some non-lawyer telling you that you "should have" a defence is not something you'd be wise to rely on.

Comment: @Stephen - And just because the court should recoginize the fair use portion does not gaurentee it will...

Answer (score 2):

[Reverse engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Legality) is a tried and trusted method in engineering. It is tried and trusted because it is *mostly* legal.  Specifically, with respect to the DCMA, Wikipedia says:

> Sec. 103(f) of the DMCA (17 U.S.C. § 1201 (f)) says that if you legally obtain a program that is protected, you are allowed to reverse-engineer and circumvent the protection to achieve the ability the interoperability of computer programs (i.e., the ability to exchange and make use of information).

When *isn't* it legal?  Primarily when you've signed an EULA that says it is illegal, or you've obtained the thing being reverse engineered illegally.

**I am not a lawyer**

Talk to one if the legalities matter.

**I am not an ethicist**

Ethics usually pertain to how you were brought up.  Talk to you mother / father / brother / sister / cousin and see what they say.

Comment: Codified law always takes precedence over license. Parts of license that say something contrary to the law in your legislature should be disregarded.

Comment: I think the OP was asking more along the lines of "is it ethical?", which is a different question (though legality *should* be considered, it's not a complete answer).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Agreed. Ethics is how you were brought up. Law is where you live. They are very different, and have very different answers.

Comment: @vartec: Yes, but if you move jurisdictions you can be in trouble!

Comment: can I publish reversed-engineered code, for example in github (with reference where it comes from and why I decompiled it)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not getting into morality here, since that's not a real good topic for a Q&A site.  Personally, in all likely cases I'm thinking of, I wouldn't mind at all if you did it to my code.

Legality is another matter, and it's something that can't properly be answered here.  If you want to know, find yourself a lawyer who specializes in "Intellectual Property" law in your jurisdiction, or whatever jurisdiction you're concerned about.  I've read a good many different things about it, and some of them conflict.  Do **not** trust legal advice you read from random people on the Internet who may not even know where you live.

From a practical point of view, nobody's likely to find out about it, so copyright law would come into the picture only insofar as you wanted to stay legal in that respect.

Comment: Yeah. That why i said wasn't so much worried about legal, as i was about whether it would bother him if he knew. Or coders in general.

Comment: Same here. I would probably never have a problem with it myself and I would be flattered if I knew that someone did.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it acceptable

The word "acceptable" is very fuzzy. Each person implies something different, based on his cultural background, unique experience and the set of values. Therefore it's impossible to answer this question.

If we narrow it down to:

> Is it legal?

Definite "no" in most jurisdictions.

and:

> Is it fair towards the author?

Again, no, if the author wants to keep his work private you must respect that.

---

There is a policy of "fair use" when you can use parts of the copyrighted work in a certain context but that implies you take the public output of the work, as a matter of speech. Decompilation, or in other words (reverse engineering, legally speaking) is an entirely different activity which has nothing to do with fair use. Here you're trying to restore the intentionally hidden work from what was made public. If they used obfuscation then your decompilation is a fact of intentional breaking of protection mechanisms. And it is punished by law.

Comment: I meant acceptable. Meaning, to put in its simplest terms, if I couldn't ask you for whatever reason, and I was looking strictly for learning, not reusing your code, for profit or project, would it make you angry? Would you be offended? Would you have a lower opinion of me, should we meet, and I tell you at some point. (Since I can't see another way for you to even know if i stick to the aforementioned restrictions.) I'm looking less at a legal issue, and more at an ethical or socially acceptable level. And frankly, I hadn't even considered asking the author. Which I should have.

Comment: As far as legal, there are exceptions to copyright for fair use for education in most places, so i don't think that is as black and white as you make it out. If it is, explain why.

Comment: @zenbike Don't forget the DMCA. "The Digital Millennium Copyright Act (DMCA) generally prohibits circumvention of technological protection measures. On its face, since circumvention is generally required for reverse engineering, this prohibition would prevent reverse engineering of those measures that control access to a copyrighted work." From [here](http://www.chillingeffects.org/reverse/). And since you can't contact the author, the exceptions for reverse engineering mentioned don't apply.

Comment: @Michael Todd: Isn't it the other way around? Reverse engineering is an activity which could lead to the protection circumvention and is therefore frowned upon.

Comment: @Michael Todd: Does the DMCA apply world-wide, or just inside the USA? If the OP and author are both in the UK, or in India, or Pakistan, or... I imagine they would have to look towards their local legislation (if there is any). Might get trickier if they live in different countries. I guess since OP didn't post their jurisdiction, USA is just assumed.

Comment: @Frustrated You're right; I automatically assumed they were in the U.S. Doesn't apply elsewhere, of course. (And the UAE is _definitely_ not the U.S.)

Comment: Explain your view of fair use, please. I understand to mean that if I am using for the purpose of education, then I am being fair to the author. You imply that I must be doing so in a public manner, which would seem to be on its face unfair to the author. Also, the exceptions to reverse engineering ask  for no publishing, which seems to lean my way. Unless I am mistaken about what you meant?

Comment: @ Frustrated: What is OP? BTW, I am a US citizen living in Dubai. So DMCA is murky. But I am less interested in a legal judgement than the moral one. What would you all be ok with if it was your code I was looking at?

Comment: @zenbike _If_ the DMCA applied to you (which it doesn't since you're not in the U.S.) _and_ you met all of the conditions (not publishing, contacting the author for permission, etc.), then, yes, you'd be able to reverse engineer for learning purposes. You're not able to fulfill those requirements, though, since you're assuming no contact with the author; therefore, the exceptions don't apply in your case.

Comment: This answer is not very useful; it makes definite statements on legal matters and does not even suggest finding a lawyer in your jurisdiction.

Comment: @zenbike: "OP" stands for "Original poster" - it refers to you (zenbike) because *you* posted the original post (namely, the question that you asked).

Comment: @ Michael Todd: Do you recognize a difference between legality and morality here? Or are you saying that you think the DMCA is the handbook for morality in this situation, perhaps because it is the closest we have to a universal handbook for these issues?

Comment: @Frustrated: Thanks. I assumed it referred to me from context, but didn't get the acronym.

Comment: @Developer Art: You're definitely wrong, at least as far as being so black-and-white in your answer. See [Reverse Engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Legality).  The correct answer is definitely greyer than you make the legalities out to be.

Comment: @zenbike I'm not making a moral statement. I'm discussing what _one_ current U.S. law states.

Comment: @M.Todd: I'm not trying to be obtuse. But I've repeatedly said that I was concerned about whether it would bother you if it was your code. Not the legal implications, which vary widely, aren't at all clear regardless, and would be better served from a lawyer if i was going to skirt the edge of the law. Which I'm not. You keep bringing back to the legal viewpoint, so I wanted to know if you see a difference, or if you are trying to say something I'm not getting. No offense was intended, if you took one.